# Alternate way to upload the favicon.ico as facing the "we don't recognize or support this file extension type"

Tags: upload, magento-2.1.2, favicons

Even changing the `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/web/catalog/base-image-uploader.js` to `acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|ico|jpe?g|png)$/i` did not help with uploading .ico. Is there any other way?

Comment: You can upload it from admin,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem can be solved by changing line 70 in :
module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml

from

```
 item name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="string">jpg jpeg gif png svg
```

to

```
 item name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="string">ico jpg jpeg gif png svg
```

please refer to this gihub issue [#5478](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5478)

NB: run php bin/magento cache:clean after edting the file, so the changes will take effect.

Comment: You are welcome, Happy that works  :)

Answer (score 2):

First, don't touch magento core files.

I had the same problem.

For solve a problem you can [Add custom favicons manually](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/favicon.html) from your theme or can use my module with a bugfix.

https://packagist.org/packages/springimport/magento2-module-favicon-bugfix

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not change files in the `vendor` directory, it's bad practice and a bad habit.

The best course of action would probably be to simply use a .png file. There really is no good reason to still use .ico files as you would really only need them for Internet Explorer 6 support - but considering that Magento 2 is not compatible with Internet Explorer 8 and below, you can safely use PNG files.

Alternatively, you can create the favicon.ico file in the custom directory of the Theme you use.

```
app/design/frontend/<YOUR_THEME_VENDOR>/<YOUR_THEME_NAME>/Magento_Theme/web/favicon.ico
```

You might need to restart your browser / clear the cache before the new favicon becomes visible as browsers tend to cache them rather "aggressively".

Comment: ...Magento_Theme/web/favicon.ico did not change the default one.

Comment: Did you make sure that your browser or another cache is not sending the old favicon.ico file? Did you make sure to re-deploy the static files via `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` if the environment you are testing on is not in development mode? Try directly accessing the .ico file in your browser and pressing CTRL + F5 to clear your browser cache for just that file specifically.